# How can I use multiple set on one update query?

Tags: mysqli

I am trying to update multiple rows with different values but I want to use only one UPDATE query for fast result.. below is what I tried but it takes long time to execute and sometimes I am getting error by the browser cannot continued executing the code, is there any solution?

require_once 'db.php';

$price = '10000';

if($_POST){

```
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM views_by_user WHERE views > 0";
    $db = new database();
    $con = $db->dbconnect();
    $res = $db->query($con, $sql_query);

    if($res){

        $total_views = TotalViews();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){     

            $email = $row['email'];
            $user_views = $row['views'];            
                $old_balance = UserOldBalance($email);

            $percentage = ($user_views / $total_views) * 100;
            $percentage = number_format($percentage, 0);
            $earned_balance = ($price * $percentage) / 100;
            $new_balance = $old_balance + $earned_balance;

            $sql_query = "UPDATE users SET balance = '$new_balance' WHERE email = '$email'";
            $db = new database();
            $con = $db->dbconnect();
            $res = $db->query($con, $sql_query);

            if($res){

               $sql_query = "UPDATE views_by_user SET views = '0' WHERE email = '$email'";
               $db = new database();
               $con = $db->dbconnect();
               $res = $db->query($con, $sql_query);

               if($res){

                echo "Balance Updated Successfully For " . $email . "<br />";

                }
                else {
                    echo "Error Updating Views...";
                }

            }
            else {
                echo "Error Updating Balance...";
            }

        }

    }
    else {
        echo "error";
    }

}
```

}

function TotalViews(){

```
$sql_query = "SELECT SUM(views) as 'total_views' FROM views_by_user";
$db = new database();
$con = $db->dbconnect();
$res2 = $db->query($con, $sql_query);

if($res2){

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2)){       
        $total_views = $row2['total_views'];
    }

}

return $total_views;
```

}

function UserOldBalance($email){

```
$sql_query = "SELECT gems_balance FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$db = new database();
$con = $db->dbconnect();
$res3 = $db->query($con, $sql_query);

if($res3){

    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res3)){
        $old_gems = $row3['gems_balance'];
    }

}

return $old_gems;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is inefficient, and we can try rewriting as a single MySQL update query.  For example, your first query could be rewritten as:

```
UPDATE users u
SET balance = gems_balance + 10000 * ROUND(views / (SELECT SUM(views) FROM views_by_user));
WHERE email = ?;
```

This eliminates the need to loop over your table, as if using a cursor.  Instead, you may execute a single statement.  If you want to update for just a given email, then bind a single value to `?` above.  If you want to update the entire table, then just remove the `WHERE` clause.

The second query, assuming you want it applied over the entire table, is just a simple blanket update:

```
UPDATE views_by_user
SET views = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but even if I use this I still need to use the loop while since the value views and email are changing on each row.

Comment: You are missing the point of how SQL works.  The above updates already operate _on each row_.  This means that, for `email1`, the `gems_balance` value for that row is used, and for `email2`, some other value is used.

Comment: I found the solution for my issue, this is how I fixed my problem I used the Case End while I SET the new value.. I will add the solution to my code thanks for your try anyway. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my issue I had to use the mysql query as below:

```
UPDATE users 
SET balance = ( case  
                when email = '$email1' then '$new_balance1'  
                when email = '$email2' then '$new_balance2' 
               end) 
WHERE email in ('$email2', '$email2')
```